# Will different kinds of sugar or coffee affect coffee syrup flavor?

Tags: coffee, sugar, syrup, espresso

This coffee syrup is basically a 2 to 1 ratio of sugar to coffee, and you boil it to a thick syrup. A person who tasted the final dish said it tasted like espresso!

What kind of effects would it get from different kinds of sugar? Would brown sugar give it a molasses taste, for example?

Would different coffees have any effect on the coffee syrup?

Comment: Could you please try to provide a link, or just add in the actual recipe since I'm sure it's just a few ingredients? We're happy to edit and make things pretty, but there are a bunch of coffee syrup recipes on food.com and it's hard to tell which kind you're talking about.

Comment: Look under my name for my coffee syrup, my member name is Abraham r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coffee syrup, like anything else cooked, will taste of the ingredients used. If you use brown sugar it will syrupy and have a molasses flavor, if you use floral honey it will taste of it. If you use a richer coffee bean it will have a richer coffee taste.

Comment: Also, how you treat the sugars during syrup making matters - eg if acid is added, you get more inversion and a more honey-like taste.

Comment: what kinds of sugar/coffee would you recommend then @rackandboneman?

Comment: That's a matter of taste @AbrahamRay, completely subjective and it depends on what you want.

Comment: ok. thanks @GdD feel free to make sugestions on how to improve my other recipes if you want on food.com. my member name is Abraham r

Comment: I would recommend to start with plain sugar and experiment with some of the inversion and caramelization effects you can get by using different cooking methods :)

Comment: thanks for the advice @rackandboneman it's just that I don't usually drink coffee myself.